# How to represent the "Triangle of Power" in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subscripts, superscripts

So, I've just seen a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOtduunD9hA) about a method of notation called "Triangle of Power", which simplifies things when it comes down to exponents, logarithms, etc. It was originally introduced in this post on Math.Stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/alternative-notation-for-exponents-logs-and-roots/165225#165225

I wanted to use it in my LaTeX documents, but couldn't figure out a way to actually write it easily; my knowledge of custom commands and positioning of symbols is not enough.

So, what I want to do is this:

[image: Triangle of Power]
And it needs to have some nice way of not providing one of the values (really, see the video if you're interested). Moreover, it should more-or-less fit in line with other notation, so it shouldn't be too big nor sticking out, though it probably will look okay if the values themselves stick out a little.

How can I implement this?

Comment: In that post from the math site, alex.jordan uses `\stackrel{y}{_x\triangle_{z}}`. You could make a simple macro as `\newcommand\PowerTriangle[3]{\stackrel{#2}{_{#1}\triangle_{#3}}}`, and use it as `$\PowerTriangle{x}{y}{z}`. There is room for improvement though, probably someone can make a better version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Working from Akiiino's answer I came up with this, which also works in display mode

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dotriangle}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-.7ex}{$\vcenter{#1\kern.2ex\hbox{$\triangle$}\kern.2ex}$}%
}

\newcommand{\tripow}[3]{% Syntax: \tripow{#1}{#2}{#3} gives you #1 ^ {#2} = #3
   \mathop{% We want it to an operator
      \mathchoice% We want different functionality in text and display mode
         {% DISPLAY MODE
            \vphantom{\dotriangle\LARGE}% \vphantom off-set: places the bottom entries.
            \rule[-1.4ex]{0.1em}{0pt}% Syntax: [<vetical drop #1>]{<left margin>}{<Should be 0>}
            _{\scriptstyle #1}% style of #1 entry
            {\overset{\scriptstyle #2}% style of #2 entry
            {\dotriangle\LARGE}}% Size of the displayed operator - should match the \vphantom off-set.
            \rule[-1.4ex]{0em}{0pt}% Syntax: [<vetical drop #3>]{<Should be 0>}{<Should be 0>} 
            _{\scriptstyle #3}% style of #3 entry
            \rule[0ex]{0.1em}{0pt}% Syntax: [<Should be 0>]{<right margin>}{<Should be 0>}
          }%
        {% TEXT MODE
            \vphantom{\dotriangle\normalsize}%
            \rule[-1.05ex]{-0.7ex}{0pt}%
            _{#1}% 
            \overset{#2}% 
            {\dotriangle\normalsize}% size in text mode
            \rule[-1.05ex]{0pt}{0pt}%
            _{#3}%
            \rule[0ex]{-0.2em}{0pt}%
          }%
        {% SCRIPT MODE
            \vphantom{\dotriangle\normalsize}%
            \rule[-1.05ex]{-0.8ex}{0pt}%
            _{\scriptstyle #1}%
            {\overset{\scriptstyle #2}%
            {\dotriangle\normalsize}}% size in script mode
            \rule[-1.05ex]{0pt}{0pt}%
            _{\scriptstyle #3}%
            \rule[0ex]{-0.3em}{0pt}%
         }%
        {}% SCRIPTSCRIPT MODE
   }%
}
```

Compiling this code

```
\begin{document}
Here we see some fundamental relations:
\begin{align}
    \tripow{x}{a+b}{}&=\tripow{x}{a}{}\cdot\tripow{x}{b}{}
    \\
    \tripow{x}{}{ab}&=\tripow{x}{}{a}+\tripow{x}{}{b}
    \\
    \tripow{x}{1/y}{}&=\tripow{}{y}{x}
    \\
    \tripow{x}{\tripow{x}{}{z}}{}&=z
        \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
    \text{or}& \tripow{x}{\tripow{x}{}{z}}{z}
    \\
    \tripow{x}{}{\tripow{x}{y}{}}&=y
        \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
    \text{or}& \tripow{x}{y}{\tripow{x}{y}{}}
    \\
    \tripow{}{y}{\tripow{x}{y}{}}&=x
        \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
    \text{or}& \tripow{x}{y}{\tripow{x}{y}{}}
    \\
    \tripow{\tripow{}{y}{z}}{y}{}&=z
        \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
    \text{or}& \tripow{\tripow{}{y}{z}}{y}{z}
\end{align}
This is a line of text. This text says alot of interesting stuff and 
does not intersect.
Here is some more in-line text followed by $\tripow{x}{y}{z}$ which is
the same as saying $x^y=z$. The text on the this line does not 
intersect either.
\end{document}
```

gives you
[image: example]

Comment: Very nice! Can you make a MathJax version that has similar behavior? You'd have to swap out `\rule` for `\Rule` and maybe `\raisebox` for `\raise`. If you get something that works, I'd employ it at the [math.se post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/alternative-notation-for-exponents-logs-and-roots/165225#165225) and cross-post back here. All the newcommmand definition stuff could go into MathJax math delimiters early in the post.

Comment: Could you release that under a license compatible with TeX?

Answer (score 9):

After some tinkering with the variants, I've come up with this:

```
\newcommand{\PowerTriangle}[3]{ \mathop{\vphantom{\triangle}}_{#1}\hspace{-0.17em}{\stackrel{#2}{\triangle}}_{#3}}
```

[image]

The subscripts are a bit lower than in the original post and it looks better in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I've attempted to create a command which will typeset the "Triangle of Power" in a nice way. My best effort so far is the following:

```
\newcommand{\tripow}[3]{ _{#1}{\stackrel{#2}{\triangle}}_{#3}}
$\tripow{x}{y}{z}$
```

The only issue is that the right subscript appears a little low. But it does allow nesting fairly well.